# Как cделать чтобы Discord бот выдал роль пользователю при подключении к voice каналу?

Tags: python, discord.py

Как сделать так чтобы человек присоединялся к воис каналу дискорд, бот выдавал ту или иную роль, а после то как человек выходит из канала роль забралась?

```
@client.event()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1084384/178576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для голосового канала:

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    role = get(member.server.roles, name="Speaker")
    is_my_channel = after.channel and after.channel.id == 776564197873287202;
    if after.channel and after.channel!=before.channel and is_my_channel:
       await client.add_roles(member, role)  
    # if before.channel and after.channel!=before.channel and is_my_channel:
    #   await client.remove_roles(member, role)
```

*для обычного канала (первоначальный ответ, возможно кому-то пригодится)*:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = get(member.server.roles, name="Admin")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, не так задал вопрос, исправил ошибку.

Comment: А как сделать проверку на подключение к каналу который мне нужен, допустим айди его 776564197873287202, а если подключаешься к другим то роль не выдается?

Comment: if after.channel.id == 776564197873287202

Comment: >>>     if after.channel.id == 776564197873287202
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: нужно добавить в оба условия `and after.channel.id == 776564197873287202`

Comment: if before.channel and after.channel.id == 776564197873287202!=before.channel:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: нужна же проверка на None, а вы ее пропустили, я поправил ответ

Comment: Бот выдает роль и сразу снимает её, в консоль не выдает ошибок.

Comment: я закоментил последний if - он был лишним (потом придумаете как снять роль), у меня к сожалению не было свободного бота под рукой

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался